# Jquery Validation works on some but not all text inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validation plugin for the first time...it's working correctly on some of the inputs in my form (simplified below), but not on others. Any idea why? In the example below, the validation works on the first input #planname, but does not work on #q8b.

---

```
<form id="form">

   <fieldset>
    <legend>Plan Name</legend>
    <span><input id="planname" type="text" name="planname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['planname']; ?>" required class="required" /></span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="childwrap" id="q8bwrap">
    <legend>Do you have an outstanding loan?</legend>
    <input id="q8b" type="text" name="q8b"   value="<?php if ($_SESSION['q8a'] == "Yes") {echo $_SESSION['q8b']; } ?>"/>%<br/>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

---

### Included in footer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

---

### This script works:

```
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    planname: {
      required: true,
      max: 23
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

---

### This one does not:

```
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    q8b: {
      required: true,
      max: 23
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

This is just for testing purposes, trying to figure out why it's not working; in the final product, q8b should not be required, but should have a maximum value of 23.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, folks - it was an error on my part. My form utilizes Bootstrap, and I'd neglected to nest my columns within a row - that was "breaking" the page and preventing the validation from working properly.

Comment: The HTML code in your OP is working.  Each question and its answer should be self-contained and apparently your actual problem is not shown in either one.  Please be more specific and post the actual code that broke it, while explaining how you fixed it.  As it stands, it makes no sense.  Malformed HTML should not break the JavaScript validation.

Answer (score 0):

Both scripts work for me.  I created this with the second script and all looks good. Maybe there is something else you are changing elsewhere in your script (not shown in your question) that is causing the issue?

```js
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    q8b: {
      required: true,
      max: 23
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">

   <fieldset>
    <legend>Plan Name</legend>
    <span><input id="planname" type="text" name="planname" value="0" required class="required" /></span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="childwrap" id="q8bwrap">
    <legend>Do you have an outstanding loan?</legend>
    <input id="q8b" type="text" name="q8b" value="0"/>%<br/>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your two scripts one after the other?

```
$( "#form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    planname: {
      required: true,
      max: 23
    }
  }
});

$( "#form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    q8b: {
      required: true,
      max: 23
    }
  }
});
```

If so, then it explains why the second is not working.

The `.validate()` method is used to initialize the plugin on your form and can only be called ***once*** on a particular `form` element.  All subsequent calls are ignored.

For multiple fields, you'd use it like this...

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        planname: {
            required: true,
            max: 23
        },
        q8b: {
            required: true,
            max: 23
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/koyrqppb/**

---

You would not need the inline `required` attribute or `class="required"` when you're already declaring your `required` rule inside of the `rules` object of the `.validate()` method.  Declaring the same rule three different ways is uselessly redundant and only makes the code harder to maintain later.